# How to use a Variable quantity in a python request url

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Can a variable quantity be used instead of the '201804101602's in  request 
 (python 3) ?

```
import requests
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/school/class201804101456"
headers = {'name': 'tom201804101456'}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: As they're just strings, why not set up a variable and then append it to `class` and `tom` in the example above?

Comment: I`m new to python, can you show me? Thanks.

Comment: You should try an learn the basics before posting in StackOverflow.

Try here:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Comment: OK, I`ll try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they're just strings, why not set up a variable and then append it to class and tom in the example above?

For example:

```
import requests
token = "201804101456"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/school/class" + token
nameHeader = "tom" + token
headers = {'name': nameHeader}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```